# On a web page with Html Table, how do I determine if a Html Row is selected or not using c#?

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and doing Test Automation - On a web page with Html Table, how do I determine if a Html Row is selected or not using c#?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing so, as testing the client is something that should be done on the client side. It would likely save you a lot of time an headaches to test your client code with JavaScript, but if you must:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804660/How-to-Parse-HTML-using-Csharp